# Ступінь порівняння прикметника новітній

Tags: прикметники

Натрапила на такий рекламний текст: "Універсальний ТБ пульт (Universal TV REMOTE) можна використовувати практично з будь-якою моделлю телевізорів! І неважливо, стара вона чи найновітніша!"
За [СУМ-11,](http://sum.in.ua/s/novitnij) відповідне значення слова новітній таке:

> 2. Новий, що відповідає сучасним вимогам; найновішого типу, конструкції і т. ін. Замість архітектурних балконів з амурчиками та
>      іншими прикрасами, новітні будинки мали стандартні, неестетичні
>      залізні балкончики (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 109); Чекають нас
>      новітнії машини. Ставай, юначе, справжнім трударем! (Григорій Бойко,
>      Про 17 літ, 1958, 15);  //  рідко. Новий, інший; не той, що був
>      раніше. І став я шукати собі для розради Новітніх друзів (Агатангел
>      Кримський, Вибр., 1965, 115).

Якщо новітній вже містить у собі значення "найновішого типу", то чи можливою є форма цього прикметника у найвищому ступені порівняння - найновітніший, чи доцільно було би замінити його на інший?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Галина Сюта** пише статтю [**"Я — РОЗУМНИЙ, ТИ — РОЗУМНІШИЙ, ВІН — НАЙРОЗУМНІШИЙ
(ЯК НЕ ПОМИЛИТИСЯ ПРИ СТУПЕНЮВАННІ ПРИКМЕТНИКІВ)"**](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine70-40.pdf), в якій знаходимо відповідь на Ваше запитання. Вона вважає, що:

> у зв’язку із соціальним призначенням реклами — будь-яким способом привернути увагу потенційного споживача, не порушуючи при цьому словотвірних норм української мови, використовуються **оказіональні слова**. До таких належать найпомідорніша, найтоматніша.

Тобто у наведених прикметниках і так зрозумілий склад: помідори, томати, тому відповідно до правил ступінь порівняння не утворюємо, однак реклама цим маніпулює. ***Сюди ж і віднесено слово "найновітніша"***. Так, Ви написали, що у самій лексемі "новітній" вже міститься значення "найновішого типу", проте у РЕКЛАМІ все ж подають вищий чи найвищий ступені порівняння, аби наголосити, що саме пульт (Universal TV REMOTE) є найкращим!)

Отже, форма прикметника **найновітніший** *не нормативна,* однак *у рекламі допускається* у зв’язку з приверненням уваги та справляння належного емоційного впливу на споживача рекламного продукту.